# Error trying to use import.jxl... statements

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am working on a program using eclipse galileo and jdk 6. The problem is that when I use any import.jxl... statement I get an error in eclipse and it won't compile. So statements like  "import jxl.write.Label;" give me an error. I don't understand why that is. It says it doesn't like the jxl statements. If I use any import.java... or import.javax... then they work fine. Any Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does jxl come from? Is the library on your path?

Answer (score 3):

in your project properties dialog (Project menu/Properties), under Java Build Path, select the 'Libraries' tab.  there you have the option of including jars or class files from other projects that you have open or jars and class files from elsewhere on your filesystem.  once you locate your jxl.jar and add it, it should show up in the tree in this Libraries tab.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to add the jxl jar file to your build path.